# COUNT query issues

Tags: sql, database, oracle, count

I'm trying to write a query in Oracle that will COUNT the number of customers who do not have any orders placed.

Here is the code I've been working with:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(customer_num)
FROM 
    orders 
INNER JOIN 
    customer ON orders.order_num = customer.customer_num,
WHERE 
    order.order_num IS NULL;
```

This is the error message:

> ORA-00903: invalid table name

Obviously this isn't working. Please help!

Comment: You have a comma before the where clause. Also I think you may want an outer join.

Comment: query part of this question should be in code format

Comment: you also have order.order_num as well as FROM orders, you have to get the table name straight.  That causes the error. but you have to also fixed te comma as per T I

Comment: @ Michael, Also, to add onto T I's response, if you have an inner join, the query is looking for connecting the customer number primary key to the order number foreign key (to the cust table).  If the customer does not have any orders placed, they would not be in the orders table, unless something is wrong with your database.  get the correct outer join (or right join) happening and they you can do the where NULL condition.

Comment: @ Michael, a piece of advice, search for an image of sql joins, print it, and keep it near to you as you learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select COUNT(customer_num) 
FROM customer LEFT JOIN orders ON customer.customer_num = orders.order_num  
WHERE orders.order_num is NULL;
```

There was a coma in there which shouldn't be there and `WHERE orders.order_num` was lacking a "s". Also you have 1 table at the plural form and the other isnt. Maybe its table `customers` and not `customer` ?

I think a LEFT JOIN would also work better for what you are trying to achieve

EDIT : Take a look at this [SQL statement to get all customers with no orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859896/sql-statement-to-get-all-customers-with-no-orders)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select COUNT(customer_num) 
FROM orders 
right JOIN customer 
ON orders.order_num = customer.customer_num
where orders.order_num is NULL;
```

Also, your customer is singular and your orders is plural, which might confuse you when writing the query.